# Can I create an ALSA virtual MIDI port with any name?

Tags: wine, alsa, midi

Can I create an ALSA virtual MIDI port with any name?
I want to run ATS-MA7-SMAF with Wine.
If the OS is Windows7 or earlier, the included virtual MIDI driver can be used, but since Wine cannot install the virtual MIDI driver, I need to create a MIDI port named "YAMAHA Virtual MIDI Device 0" there is.

Comment: The name of a MIDI port is determined by the driver/program that creates it. In theory, it would be possible to write your own program that passes through messages to another port.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought it would be easy to create a port of any name, like loopMIDI for Windows. Someday I want to write software like your advice.